# Paypal header issues

Tags: paypal

I get this error when testing donations, the result is the same in test and live environments. "Error Payment approval failed with message :Security error Security header is not valid" I searched every forum out there and tried every solution I could find with the same result every time.

I checked the name, key, and secret 1000 times and then reset it and again tried 100 times.

I tried using the login name as suggested on a forum and that did not help.

I removed the payment option and re-added it.

I tried the test variables in the live settings via your forum and no go...

I tried this and it came back ok so I assume paypal works (Info changed 4 security) "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?&user=info_api1.rockymountainmustang.org&pwd=JPJUK7LxxxxxYLR&signature=A.MRLXfmAocfnxxxxxRHc67jlS52IYYS7LRw&version=70.0&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&RETURNURL=http://www.paypal.com/test.php&CANCELURL=http://www.paypal.com/test.php&PAYMENTACTION=Sale&AMT=50&CURRENCYCODE=USD"

Comment: Hi Joe welcome to civicrm.stackexchange. This sounds frustrating. Could you include the version of civicrm you are running along with the CMS (and cms version) just to help people figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: would be nice to know if you're using paypal express, standard or pro type of the processor. can you post a screenshot of the configuration page?'

Comment: I am having the same problem.  Using CiviCRM Version 5.18.4 for WordPress, and connecting using "PayPal - Website Payments Pro".  I used the URLs pre-programmed into the CiviCRM form, and filled in:

Sandbox Account -->  Username; 
AccessToken -->Signature; 
Secret -->Password
 I just get the error "Security error Security header is not valid"